# What is the recommended settings for video editing using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, screen-capture

I am quite new for using `FFmpeg`, and I am using `FFmpeg` in screen recording. I checked the online documentation in this link [ffmpeg documentation "Capturing your Desktop / Screen Recording"](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop), but I didn't find sufficient information.

I have a 4k laptop with invidia GPU, and I am using the below command to screencast the video (4k, 60 f/s), and audio from my laptop.

```sh
ffmpeg -video_size 3840x2160 \
 -framerate 60 \
 -f x11grab -i :1 -f pulse -ac 2 -i default \
 -c:v libx264 \
 -crf 0 \
 -qp 0 \
 -preset ultrafast videoname.mp4
```

I have some problems in these settings as following:

1. The output video is too large, and I need to reduce the size without touch the quality at all.
2. The output video seems to be not a row video, and it takes too much time in video editing decoding and encoding. I am not sure if there is a recommended setting for video editing. As I did some search and found the above is advised, but in practice perspective, it is not efficient.

Below is my Linux distro information:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description   : Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release       : 20.04
Codename      : focal
```

Comment: You might get a faster Answer at [**SuperUser.com**](https://superuser.com/) since this about using a command line tool (& not a programming issue). There you can use your S.O account to click _"**Join This Community**"_ and then post a copy of your Question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Use a proxy

4k footage is often edited by using a smaller (1280x720 for example) proxy video. This allows the editor to be more responsive and less slow during the editing process. When the final edited video is exported the editing software will refer to the original 4k footage to create the output, so using a proxy does not reduce the quality of the final output.

Intra-frame H.264:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "scale=-2:720,format=yuv420p" -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset fast -tune fastdecode -g 1 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

If you prefer ProRes:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "scale=-2:720" -c:v prores_ks -profile:v proxy -c:a pcm_s16le output.mov
```

Refer to the documentation for your editor to see if this is an option for you.

Comment: I am using Hitfilm pro as video editing. My main concern is related to enhance video editing encoding (processing) speed. I could ignore the file size but I can't touch the quality and want to enhance the editing speed.

Comment: Could you please update your answer by the recommended settings to make the video encode fast with 4k. As per my understanding, you need me to use a different encoding which could make the file size bigger, Is this correct?

Comment: @MoustafaMahmoud There is nothing I can suggest on the ffmpeg side of things to make Hitfilm Pro (which I've never heard of) export a video faster unless you decrease the width x height or use a proxy. I know nothing of that editor. *"Could you please update your answer by the recommended settings to make the video encode fast with 4k"* Are you referring to your ffmpeg command that captures the desktop? Or outputting the final video from Hitfilm? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? It seems like none of us are proving the answer you are looking for.

Comment: The actual problem is the output video seems to take much time to be encoded again in the video editing software. I am asking for a recommendation to make the output video from ffmpeg easier to be encoded again for the video editing.

Comment: For example, you mentioned this part in your answer ```-c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset fast -tune fastdecode```Could you please explain if this preset and tune will make the video editing faster? Does this affect the quality?

Comment: @MoustafaMahmoud When I answered your question I thought you were basically asking *"How to make video editor more responsive and less slow when editing 4k?"*, but now I see you are asking *"How to export video faster from Hitfilm Pro?"*. I can't answer that. I don't know anything about that editor. ffmpeg isn't really part of that problem.

Comment: I think you didn't get my question, My question is still ***How to make video editor more responsive and less slow when editing 4k?*** I just added more information if this could help.

Comment: I can't get what I need to edit to keep the quality 4k and make the video editor more responsive and less slow when editing 4k. This includes any recommendations for other encoding or other settings.

Comment: @MoustafaMahmoud Answer is to use a proxy.

Comment: Can we use ```ProRes``` direct in screen recording or this could affect the quality?

Comment: @MoustafaMahmoud Yes, you can use ProRes direct in screen recording.

Comment: Could you please share with me how can we record direct using prores? I think this could help me a lot to close this quesiton.

Comment: @MoustafaMahmoud `ffmpeg -video_size 3840x2160 -framerate 60 -f x11grab -i :1 -f pulse -ac 2 -i default -c:v prores -c:a pcm_s16le videoname.mov`

Answer (score 1):

you coul could use -crf 17 as that is visually  indistinguishable and way faster

Comment: ```Crf``` could reduce the size but will not enhance the encoding for video editing.

Comment: it will reduce the bitrate, not the size. Also it does speed up the process. And also when the crf gets lower, you need way more time to process for a very minimal quality gain (under 17 practically invisible)

Comment: I tried to do this but it didn't help in video processing.

Comment: also if you want a smaller filesize choose a slower preset.

Comment: Or set the -b with the bitrate you want. But you can't expect having fast encoding, small filesize and high quality at the same time.

Comment: you'll need to lower one of them at least

Comment: I need fast decoding in the video editing without lose the quality. The file size reduction is preferred also.